# Does Alljoyn need root access?

Tags: android, alljoyn

I've recently found out about Alljoyn and I would like to ask if developing Alljoyn app needs Android devices to be rooted. Also can you point a simple demo to develop apps using Alljoyn. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Also, can I use services of different release versions? For example using version x on release, then y on the other services. Right now, the current version for Release SDK is 15.09.00a and other services are lower. Is it okay to use them that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need root access in order to develop Android applications that use Alljoyn library.
The samples are located in the following folder (SDK Android 15.09a):

```
core/alljoyn-15.09.00a-rel/java/samples
```

Not sure about using different version, for instance Core SDK 15.09 and Lighting SDK 15.04